# GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c

Even though framework search path is given and google framework is added in `Build Phases`, it shows `GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h` file not found as error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to do this**

1. Click on your project (**targets**)
2. Click on **Build Settings**
3. Under **Framework search paths** (set your framework path)

Following information for **getting framework search paths**

1. Right click on your framework folder (for ex: GoogleMaps.framework)
2. select **Get info**
3. copy the path from **General->where** and paste this path in your framework search path (path should contain in single line)

need reference use this link https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/upgrading-sdk

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you have taken project from another user than the third party frameworks will not added in your project. So Add the framework again in your project and the xcode will write the path in Library Search Path..

And To solve this problem permanently , you can write **$(SRCROOT)** in Library Search Path. In this case, if you send your project to other than user has to add just framework only.

For example:

$(SRCROOT)/myproject/Resources/ThirdPartyCode/GoogleAdMobAdsSdkiOS-6.8.0

May it helps you..